# How come this account hasn't been nuked?

Tags: discussion, spam

I've stumbled across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19993605) and succeeded (obviously)

> Reputed Nashik Escort Services - Karishma Sharma
>
> Best Nashik Escort Services in Nashik providing every kind of erotic services to his clients in an affordable manner, available 24 hours. Satisfying with both sexual and non-sexual activities to his clients for his physical and mental relaxation. [spam link]

The post is rightfully locked as spam. Now I'm mentally relaxed.

But strangely, the user who posted this (1 rep) didn't get their account deleted. Is there hope for this user to post a programming-related question or answer?

Comment: It's a reasonably new account, it's possible the mods just haven't gotten to it.

Comment: @NobodyNada, thanks for the edit, the link was already changed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The *changed* link redirected a bunch of times before landing me on an apparently malicious page.

Comment: it wasn't intentional! I didn't think someone would try to click on it. Duly noted for the next time

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre by including a spam link in this post, you increase the number of reputable websites on which the link appears, meaning it is seen as more legitimate by search engines and spam blockers. You also increase the probability of people clicking on it (accidentally or otherwise), potentially exposing people to dangerous malware.

Comment: It was a made-up link, not a real link. But it didn't bring anything to the question, so ok!

Comment: I dunno… I'd need to see the link in order to determine if it's really spam. I'd *really* need to see that link. **Really**.

Comment: revision 1 of the question contains it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/369333/1

Comment: Doesn't look like spam to me. I'm sure they just wanted help with their website's css; that's why they posted the link so that we see the problem and help fix it.

Comment: Sorry, should have added some smileys to make it even more obvious that I’m not serious.

Comment: I figured that out eventually.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It was deleted by six users voting spam so the moderators never saw it. This is why the account remains.

However, the account is unusable because the IP address is spam blocked.

Every so often one of us will check for accounts with deleted posts to see if there are any spam accounts left lying around and delete them then.

Oh yeah. I destroyed the account and also notified the SU mods as there was a linked account over there.

Comment: also can you explain what to do in those cases? should I flag one of my own posts with a custom flag?

Comment: If a 1 rep user has 2 posts auto deleted by spam flags... they should really just be auto nuked. IMO

Comment: @TravisJ I believe that there's a MSE feature request for something along those lines.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I wouldn't bother. The account will be IP blocked and I'm sure that someone will eventually notice the account lying around and nuke it.

Comment: I can't help but feel "wait till somebody notices the crap laying around while we already got a system in place telling us it's definitely crap" is an odd way of going about it.

Comment: @Mast - I know, but suggestions have been made to automatically clean up accounts whose only posts are spam and until those are implemented (or not as the case may be) it's the only way we have of finding them.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be auto-nuked. It could simply notify mods with a daily list of potential spam accounts.

Comment: @TravisJ: To achieve what? What is the goal of that suggestion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Spamless future?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Refer to Chris's answer above: the IP address is spam blocked already. I do not see what nuking the account history accomplishes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The point? Maybe in this place the IP is blocked, but I have seen the case where it was the first post from a 1 rep user, the post was deleted from spam flags, and no action was taken with regards to the user account. They then went on to post again. Why allow them to continue? What is the goal of that? Why would you want to allow spammers more chances to create content?